# problem in using "For" & "If" in Dataframes (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

i'm having a problem with dealing with for & if statement combined, when using the same concept on lists like the following

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
B = [3,6]

for item in A:
  if item not in B:
     print(item)
```

the output here will be logical which is (1,2,4,5)

My problem is in the following code down below

```
AD_Neighborhood = AD_Areas['Area'] # (Bigger list)
AD_Neigh_Coffee = AD_grouped['Neighborhood'] # (Smaller List) 

AD_No_Coffee=[]
for Area in AD_Neighborhood:
    if Area not in AD_Neigh_Coffee:
        AD_No_Coffee.append(Area)
```

the output is showing all values AD_Neighborhood instead of returning values that are not in the Smaller list.

Can someone please help me with this issue

Comment: Can you share the contents of `AD_Areas['Area']` and `AD_grouped['Neighborhood']`, or at least a subset that would allow us to reproduce the problem? It's possible that the values in each column aren't exactly identical, which would make `in` not work.

Comment: both data are identical, i tried to convert both to list " AD_Neighborhood = AD_Areas['Area'].values.tolist()" &  "AD_Neigh_Coffee = AD_grouped['Neighborhood'].values.tolist()" the code worked. Can i please get an explanation if it's possible was the issue, maybe index problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because you are not iterating over lists but using pandas series.
You can convert list to series like below:

```
AD_Neighborhood = AD_Areas['Area'].tolist() # (Bigger list)
AD_Neigh_Coffee = AD_grouped['Neighborhood'].tolist() # (Smaller List) 

AD_No_Coffee=[]
for Area in AD_Neighborhood:
    if Area not in AD_Neigh_Coffee:
        AD_No_Coffee.append(Area)
```

Also in general, I would say, you should avoid loops as much as possible. See if you can solve using pd.apply. But if the length of the lists is not huge(>1k), it should not be a big problem.